# JavaScript query all the class and check if any are set to true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this logic below that is getting all the value using the class name and then doing a looping. In the loop I am checking if any of the values is true. I wanted to see if there is a way to do this without the loop can I just query the class making sure that just one is true then set the ResultValue to true?

```js
                    let File = false;
                    $('.fileClass').each((index, element) => {
                        console.log(element.value);
                        if (element.value == true) {
                            File = "True"
                        }     
                    });
                    if (File === false) {
                        $('#hasFile').val('');
                    }
                    
                     $('#ResultValue').html($('#hasFile').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hf1" name="hf1" class="fileClass" value="False">
 <input type="hidden" id="hf2" name="hf2" class="fileClass" value="False">
 <input type="hidden" id="hf2" name="hf2" class="fileClass" value="False">
 
 
  <input type="hidden" id="hasFile" name="hasFile" value="True">
  
  
   <label id="ResultValue"></label>
```

Comment: You could use an attribute selector, but it is not a good idea to use an attribute selector for value.

Comment: The `value` property of DOM element nodes is not a function, so `element.value()` is an error.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270553/working-equivalent-for-method-some-in-javascript-or-jquery.

Comment: Also `class"fileClass"` is incorrect; there should be an `=` in the middle.

Comment: Sorry I corrected that

Comment: How did you change the value of input？

Comment: `const hasFile = Array.from(document.querySelector('.fileClass')).some(inp => inp.value === 'True');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, you can querySelector on the CSS class and check if the Value is set to `True`

```js
const hasFiles = $('.fileClass[value="True"]').length > 0;

if (!hasFiles) $('#hasFile').val('');
    
$('#ResultValue').html($('#hasFile').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="hf1" name="hf1" class="fileClass" value="False">
<input type="hidden" id="hf2" name="hf2" class="fileClass" value="False">
<input type="hidden" id="hf3" name="hf3" class="fileClass" value="False">
 
<input type="hidden" id="hasFile" name="hasFile" value="True">
  
<label id="ResultValue"></label>
```